# Correct pattern to select while able to search

Tags: user-research, material-design

Situation: We have a list of items, which can be multi-selected. However, we can also have a search field which allows us to filter the list.

Problem: Let's say I have a huge list of items. I selected several items on the first page of a table, then I enter a new query in a search field, select several more items and then I remove the search query. I see a full list again, however, I don't know what I have selected.

Example: 
1)I select several items on a first table page;
2)I search for several items that are on, let's say, 5th table page;
3)I remove search query

Question: How properly inform a user, what he has selected? Have you ever saw similar search + select pattern?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

We have a similar component in our system. For solving this, we use chips showing what the user have already selected and we placed the search field bellow them, like this:

[image]